# React-native await useEffect functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to retrieve a field from Firestore but how can I say to wait to do the return until the function into `useEffect` has been completed?

This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
      handlClick();
  }, []);

  const handlClick = async() => {
    setRestaurant([]);
    db.doc(idBranch).get().then(data => {
        const branchData = data.data();
        setRestaurant(brn => [...brn, branchData]);
    })
  }

  return (
    <View>
        <Text> Name: {restaurant.Name} </Text>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This chunk of code may be helpful:

```
const [isHandleClickCall, setHandleClickCall] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        await handlClick();
        setHandleClickCall(true);
    })();
}, []);

const handlClick = async () => {
    setRestaurant([]);
    db
        .doc(idBranch)
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
            const branchData = data.data();
            setRestaurant((brn) => [...brn, branchData]);
        });
};

return (
    isHandleClickCall && (
        <View>
            <Text> Name: {restaurant.Name} </Text>
        </View>
    )
);
```

Comment: Still nothing.. He call the return before that handlClick have finished